# An application or python program that shows an uploaded video on youtube or vimeo from x to y seconds?

Tags: video, python, video-streaming

The purpose of this would be to stream specific parts of already uploaded videos from youtube or vimeo in a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest to this I've found yet: http://youtuberepeater.com